# React Semantic UI with Typescript errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui

I'm currently converting one of my components to a .tsx file and I've run into some weird errors on the semantic ui components that I am currently using and I can't for the life of my figure out what is going on.

[image]

[image]

any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

SemanticUI use named export and import so the import should be

```
import { Search, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";

// or 
import { Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Search } from "semantic-ui-react";
```

instead of

```
import Search from "semantic-ui-react";
import Icon from "semantic-ui-react";
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the response!, I am currently importing the semantic UI components as you stated
import { Dropdown, Search, Icon, Tab, Menu, Breadcrumb } from 'semantic-ui-react';

Comment: I make a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hill-bx6kw?file=/src/Demo2.tsx. Can you cross check any difference between yours and mine? check the tsconfig as well.

Comment: Or if you can simulate the error in codesandbox, it would be great for us to debug.

Comment: thanks for the help, I was able to resolve the issue by adding "@types/semantic-ui"

Comment: strange. `@types/semantic-ui` has not been updated for 2 years. The type definition is already integrated with  `semantic-ui` library itself. Maybe you are using a pretty old version of it.